# HTTP Get Request - Android - Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{

Tags: java, android, http, get

I have no idea why I am getting this error and I have no idea why as I have used this method for HTTP requests before. Help?

I don't really know what to do, the error is pointing at when I execute the http request. Any suggestions?

Thanks for helping.

Error:

```
02-22 22:21:37.588  16029-16029/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio, PID: 16029
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio/com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Code

```
package com.tamrefrank.www.listviewandroidstudio;
//All the imports happen when you auto complete. Often you may have erros when you copy paste things directly because libraries may not get imported
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private String [] drinks;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //set the content view to activity_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://stampwatch.herokuapp.com/");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            response = client.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
            int b;
            while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                stringBuilder.append((char) b);
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.print(jsonObject);

    drinks = new String[3];
        drinks[0] = "hi";
        drinks[1] = "5";
        drinks[2] = "3";
 /**
  * Lists require adapters-Adapters are the place that we store the various data items we want
  to appear in the Lists. This will be handled in an adapter.
  */

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//We will create the array adapter and reference it to our individual List item from the ListView and then to the array we just created- Drinks.
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,drinks);

//We finally will connect the adapter to the List View
        ListView drinkLists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Set the drinks array to the adapter below
        drinkLists.setAdapter(adapter);



    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Network requests can only be done in a non UI thread (pretty much everything except the main thread). Its a android thing to prevent freezing the UI and potentially causing ANRs. Move your network code to a separate thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, the important info is usually provided by the 'Caused by' line: 
 `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. 
 Refer to this exception in the documentation.